Function describing the probability of next event given the distribution of the inter-event time
I am doing a machine learning task to forecast the occurrence of some events. I want to find a function that describes the probability of an event happening at time $t$ so that I can use this function for supervised learning.

What I know: Data for the inter-event time intervals, which can be approximated by some distribution. Suppose that the probability density function of the time interval between events is $f(t)$.

What I want: I would like to find a function for the probability of the next event happening during the inter-event interval, such that the value of the function increases from $0$ at the end of the previous event to $1$ at the start of the next event within the inter-event interval.


What I am thinking at the moment is to use the cumulative distribution function, $F(t)=\int_0^t f(x) dx$: Suppose that a particular inter-event interval has duration $T$. Based on the distribution of the inter-event intervals, the probability of the event happening in $[0, T]$ is $F(T)$, and the probability of the event happening in $[0, t]$ for $t\leq T$ is $F(t)$. The function
$$P(t)=\frac{F(t)}{F(T)}$$
increases from $0$ to $1$ in $[0, T]$.
However, I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it. Is there any mathematically rigorous way of finding such a function? Thanks.

I do not quite understand. If the next event after time $0$ occurs at time $T$ (since $T$ is the inter-event gap) then for $0<t < T$ I would have thought the probability it occurs in the interval $(0,t]$ is $0$.

If instead $t_\max$ is the maximum possible gap between events (possibly $+\infty$), then what you are saying makes more sense.  You can use your data and model to estimate a probability density $f(t)$ or a cumulative distribution function  $F(t)$ for the event gap $T$, where $F(t)=\int_0^t f(x) ,dx$ and $f(t)=\frac{d}{dt} F(t)$ and where $F(0)=0$ and $F(t_\max)=1$ with the additional constraints that $f(t)$ is non-negative and $F(t)$ is weakly increasing.  Your $P(0 < T \le t)=F(t)$.

You model the inter-event times by some distribution which is fine.

Is your model a continuous or discrete distribution?

If it is continuous the probability for an event happening "at time $t$" is zero. It is however reasonable to ask for the probability of the event happening in an interval.

What interval shall we take when we want the probability of the "next" event?

"Suppose that a typical inter-event interval has duration $T$." What do you mean by this?

I think a reasonable answer to your question is: assume the distribution is continuous and that no event has happened yet. Then the probability for the next (the first!) event happening before a fixed time $t$ is $\mathbb P(\tau<t)=F(t)$ where $F$ is the distribution function. A typical example is the exponential distribution: $F(t)=1-e^{-\lambda t}\,.$ And typically we assume that the inter-event times are independent.



Hi Kurt, thank you so much for your answer. The distribution is continuous and the inter-event times can be assumed to be independent. What I want is to design a function that increases from 0 to 1 in every inter-event region so that I can use it to train my machine learning model. For example, if I know the next event is going to happen $T$ seconds after the previous one, how can I find a function that represents something similar to the probability of the event occurring in $[t, t+dt]$? I don't want to use a Dirac delta function because it is not useful for supervised learning.
